# choice equivalent in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: variables, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I recently refactored my declartive pipeline into a scripted form. Even if everything seems to work fine, I have a problem coming from the initialization of a multiple valued paramenter.

In my declarative pipeline, I was using the following definition of multiple valued parameter (which was working as it should):

```
    parameters {

        choice(choices: ['fix', 'major', 'minor', 'none'], description: "Increase version's number: MAJOR.MINOR.FIX", name: "VERSIONING")

    }
```

I refactored it into this form for the scripted pipeline:

```
    properties([
        parameters([
            choice(choices: ['fix\nmajor\nminor\nnone'], description: "Increase version's number: MAJOR.MINOR.FIX", name: "VERSIONING"),
        ]),
    ])
```

The problem is that when I realised that something wasn't working as it should, and printed the variable value with a `sh """echo "Versioning parameter check:" ${params.VERSIONING}"""` step, I got this from the Jenkins' console:

> Versioning parameter check: false

Which is both a value not in the list, and of a different type (boolean instead of string).

**Is there a way to implement multiple value parameter initialization in Jenkins scripted pipelines?**
Why this directive doesn't work out of the box in the scripted pipeline, whereas it does in the declarative type?
Is this a bug or *am I doing something wrong*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the other option for defining choice parameter:

```
    properties([
        parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
           choices: 'fix\nmajor\nminor\nnone\n',
           name: 'VERSIONING',
           description: "Increase version's number: MAJOR.MINOR.FIX"
        ],
        ]),
    ])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is absolutely fine. You just need to pass the choices as list items and not as \n seperated values.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(choices: ['fix', 'major', 'minor', 'none'], description: "Increase version's number: MAJOR.MINOR.FIX", name: "VERSIONING"),
    ])
])
```

Answer (score 0):

We use the following for a choice parameter, so it looks like your own definition but without the brackets:

```
properties([
        parameters([
            choice(choices: 'fix\nmajor\nminor\nnone', description: "Increase version's number: MAJOR.MINOR.FIX", name: "VERSIONING"),
        ]),
    ])
```

If you want the default value to be empty, just add an empty first choice like this:

```
choice(choices: '\nfix\nmajor\nminor\nnone'
```